# How to target only li item and not radio button inside it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have list items inside UL. I want to click on a specific list item and execute a click even ,but there is a radio button inside the li and when I click on that also, the click even is trigger. How do I target on the li item and not the radio inside it as well. I tried with the :not selector , it did do the trick. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
<li>
    <h5><a class="tooltiptext" href="show">Click</a></h5>
    <label for="itemA">
        <img src="images/templates/template1.png"></img>
    </label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="itemA" class="chooseItem" name="chooseTemplate" value="itemA" checked>
    Select
</li>
```

```js
$("li:nth-child(1):not(input[type='radio']").click(function(e){
})
```

It works but when I click on the radio I do not want to trigger the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the target of the event isn't the radio or it's associated label  since clicking on label will change radio state

```
$("li:nth-child(1)").click(function(e){
   if(!$(e.target).is('label[for], :radio') ){
      // not a radio click heree
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like following.

```
 $("li:nth-child(1)").click(function(e){
     if(!$(e.target).is(':radio')) {
         //you code goes here
     }
 })
```